# explanation for call expansion failing

Tags: batch-file, substitution, expand, modifiers

I'm looking for some tips in troubleshooting the failure of call to expand t, z, and a.

Example:

```
for /F "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b "%source%\*." '
) do if not exist "%target%\%%~nF.jpg" copy "%source%\%%~F" "%target%\%%~nF.jpg"

for /F "delims=" %%B in (
  'dir /b "%target%\*.jpg"'
) do echo Size: %%~fB
```

This example runs perfectly, but when I edit that last line to be

```
%%~zB
```

I get multiple lines of output that just say Size:

Separately, if I just run

```
for /F "delims=" %%B in (
  'dir /b "%target%\*.jpg"'
) do echo Size: %%~zB
```

in a batch file by itself, it runs as expected, showing me actual file sizes.  I've tried the same with %~a and %~t and get the same results; no output when run with the other copy sequence, and correct output when run alone.

Not sure what's going on here since %~f works just fine.  Thanks to anyone that can help.  I don't want to run two batch files.  Shouldn't be necessary IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you carefully examine the output using `%%~fB`. The report is probably showing the **current** directory, not `%target%` (at least, it does for me...)

Fix:

```
PUSHD %target%

for /F "delims=" %%B in (
  'dir /b "*.jpg"'
) do echo Size: %%~zB

POPD
```

Comment: Winner winner!  Thanks for the suggestion.  Turns out that when I ran the shorter version, I was running it from the directory that had all the target files.  Back to the drawing board now to figure out if I can get this to work from outside the target directory...Unless you can tell me up front that it won't work, saving just a few shreds of sanity for me...

Comment: Just gave in and assumed the PUSHD and POPD commands.  All is calm now on the western front.  Thanks again!